# Multiple pusle width modulation

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, inverter

I'm really struck in solving the following question

> The single-phase full-bridge voltage source inverter (VSI), shown in
>   figure, has an output frequency of 50 Hz. It uses unipolar pulse width
>   modulation with switching frequency of 50 kHz and modulation index of
>   0.7. For \$V_{in}=100\$ V DC, \$L = 9.55 \$ mH, \$C = 63.66 \mu \$F and \$R = 5\; \Omega \$, the amplitude of the fundamental component in
>   the output \$V_o \$(in Volt) under steady-state is ?
>   [image: enter imagedescription here]

Here is my approach. I'm using the following formula of the fourier series of the output voltage
$$V_{O} = \sum_{n=1,3,5}^{\infty} \frac{8V_{in}}{n\pi} \sin(n\gamma) \sin \left( \frac{nd}{2} \right) \sin(n\omega t)$$ 
where, \$ 2d = \$ total pulse width per half cycle. \$ \gamma \$ is defined as
[image]

I'm getting \$2d=1.5 ms \$ which is giving me answer way much less than the actual. The answer is in the range of \$ 60 - 64\$ V.
What is the procedure for solving such type of problems ?

Comment: What do you understand is the modulation index - is it related to duty cycle?

Comment: It is the ratio of reference voltage to the carrier voltage. I don't think it is related to duty cycle.

Comment: I think to work this out you need duty cycle and modulation index. I'm assuming that "the fundamental component" referred to is the 50 Hz component and that the problem boils down to the transfer function of a low pass filter. This doesn't appear to be what you are doing but i could be wrong.

Comment: LC network does not seems like a low pass filter, its Laplace transfer function is coming out to be \$ 1/(1 + LC s^2) \$. And for multiple pulse width modulation how would you define duty cycle ?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes you were right it was a second order low pass filter. I was previously neglecting resistance. http://nptel.ac.in/courses/108105066/PDF/L-37(DP)(PE)%20((EE)NPTEL).pdf says that modulation index relates  the inverter’s dc-link voltage and the magnitude of pole voltage (fundamental component) output by the inverter. So if we multiply modulation index by input dc we must get fundamental output peak by the inverter. I really don't understand much about modulation index though.

Comment: I'm guessing that mod index of 70% means that maximum duty is 85% and minimum duty is 15% i.e. a delta of 70%. If this is true then the "analogue" peak / peak voltage on one half of the bridge is 70% of 100 volts i.e. 70 volts. Because it is a bridge output, the p/p becomes 140 V. So this is effectively a 50 Hz sinewave of 140 volts p/p. This boils down to how much the LC filter modifies this. Resonant point of LC is 204.66 Hz and Q is \$R\sqrt{C/L}\$.

Comment: Q comes out at 0.408 so that's close to critical damping and the 50 Hz would probably end up being within a volt of 98.99 volts RMS IMHO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53322/discussion-between-ansh-kumar-and-andy-aka).