# Variation of generator working frequency with load

Tags: power, frequency, generator, load

[image]

[image]

I am confused with problem no 68. I have added my attempt. I am getting optionA but the book says it should be optionB. Please guide me where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Maybe you should consider that a 4 MW load at 50 Hz will be slightly less than 4 MW as the frequency drops below 50 Hz when the 3.5 MW load is attached.

Comment: Yes, it is decreasing from 50hz at 12MW to 49.417hz at 15.5MW

Comment: Read what I said.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you are saying

Comment: If the frequency lowers, do you need to consider that the output voltage lowers and hence the power output lowers so 4 MW at 50 Hz might be somewhat less than 4 MW at a lower frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see how the answer may be 49.917 Hz.

Under no load conditions the output frequency is 52.5 Hz and under a full load of 15 MW it is 50 Hz. However the actual load placed on the generator is 12 MW + 3.5 MW hence the load is 15.5 MW. This means the output frequency is slightly lower than 50 Hz.

Each MW lowers the frequency by 0.16666 Hz hence, starting at 52.5 Hz the frequency lowers by 15.5 x 0.166666 Hz = 2.583333 Hz hence 52.5 Hz lowers to 49.916666 Hz.

Ignore my comments about the power lowering with frequency - I was just trying to get my head around the questions subtleties. It's unclear why you began with 52.5 Hz and dropped this in favour of 52 Hz as the open load output frequency.

I also think there may be an anomaly in the question regards the three 4 MW loads being fed at 50 Hz - this contradicts the 5% droop that I take to mean the output frequency will be higher by 5% at no-load compared to 15 MW full-load.

Comment: 1 source also suggests answer to be optionC. Finally which one of the 4 options is best ?

Comment: This problem was asked in GATE 2007 (Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering) in India. Now different coaching institutes have suggested different answers to this problem as there was no official answer. So, some say A, some B and some C. Which one should I follow if a similar question is asked again?

Comment: There is no "best" answer if one accepts that there is a contradiction in the question as per the anomaly I mentioned. Either it is 15 MW load that droops the no load frequency down to 50 Hz or it is 12 MW that droops it to 50 Hz; both can't be right. If 15 MW droops f to 50 Hz then 15.5 MHz will droop f to 49.917 Hz.

Comment: So, when answering set out your assumptions and point out the contradiction.

Comment: It is mentioned in the problem that generator is feeding 12MW at 50hz. So, I took 12MW droops f to 50hz and got 49.417hz.

Comment: How can option C be possible? I can understand option A and B's possibility.

Comment: I can’t see how option c is possible!

Comment: Under assumption that measuring interval is significantly larger than speed governor's settling time (`t_m >> t_s`).  
5% droop means that engine/generator with no load run at 105% of full load speed at **full input power**, thus **speed governor** can keep output frequency at 50Hz with loads 0-15MW by reducing power. Thus, output **frequency will start to drop if load exceeds 15MW**. This clears ambiguity in the question leaving only option B correct.

Comment: @friendzis, why not option A?

Comment: @NikhilKashyap Because the frequency drop is 1/6 Hz/MW (`50Hz *1,05 @ 0W`, `50Hz @ 15MW`). At 15,5MW freq is `50 - (15,5 - 15) * 1/6 = 50 - 1/12 ~= 49,917`. You get option A at the same 1/6 Hz/MW freq drop, with 50Hz @ 12MW. I do not grasp how you get 52Hz @ 0W load.

Comment: @NikhilKashyap your plot should look something like this https://i.imgur.com/g2uE6T2.png (quality is super low, but should do the job)

Comment: @friendzis your explanation is precisely my answer but the focal point has moved to discuss, amongst other things, why the question appears to contradict itself by stating three 4 MW loads should be at 50 Hz.

Comment: @friendzis, how can the frequency be constant from 0-15MW? My instructor didn't teach anything like this. He always made frequency decrease with increase in P. To keep 50hz at 12MW, I made that graph from 52hz.

Comment: @Andyaka please help me with this problem https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350657/full-bridge-vsi-problem

Comment: @Andyaka, please guide me something on the problem. I have seen the same problem posted 1 year back here and your comments on it. It will be really helpful for me. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285369/multiple-pusle-width-modulation

Comment: I’m very busy today and also, because I didn’t answer the original question there is a strong chance it’s because I couldn’t